# meaning of 'put in for your twenty'

Tags: meaning

Police Officer: "You know, take my advice. You get busted back to walking a beat at your age? Put in for your twenty."

I googled 'put in for' and 'your twenty'.
It says 'put in for' means 'ask for something' and 'your twenty' is a code for 'my location is'.

And I'm counfused. How is 'put in for your twenty' to be accepted?
Please help me!

Comment: I think in this case it’s not your “10-20 (location) it’s your 20 year retirement.

Comment: then it means 'You get busted back to walking a beat at your age? just retire (from a police officer)'?

Comment: -Yes. That’s right

Comment: Oh, it makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jim is correct in the comments.  Put in for your twenty means, retire at full pension.  Most policemen and other civil servants are eligible for full pensions at 20 years.

Comment: I think you're right regarding police officers. Also firefighters and members of the armed forces. However civil servants and local government officers don't have that option after 20 years. It's got a lot to do with the physical demands of the job.